# What about a Cayley n-complex for n>2?

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, cayley-graphs

Let $G$ be a finitely presented group. The [Cayley graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_graph) of the finite generating set is a $1$-complex where the $0$-cells are the elements of $G$ and the $1$-cells are given by the generators (connecting two elements). The [Cayley complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_complex) of the finite presentation is a $2$-complex where the $1$-skeleton is the Cayley graph, and the $2$-cells are given by the relations ([here](https://youtu.be/uGc4tGDtpRc) is a nice YouTube video on it by [Daniel Tubbenhauer](https://www.dtubbenhauer.com/)).

Let us call *Cayley $n$-complex* of a finite presentation, the corresponding Cayley graph if $n=1$, and the corresponding Cayley complex if $n=2$, as mentioned above.

**Question**: What about a Cayley $n$-complex made from a finite presentation for $n>2$ (whose $r$-skeleton is a Cayley $r$-complex, for $r<n$)?

I am looking for obstructions preventing such a generalization to all the torsion-free finitely presented groups, and/or references discussing such a generalization to all or a large class of them.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/478588/84284) is my effort to see what such a generalization might look like.

Comment: Isn't what you are looking for just the $n$-skeleton of a model for $EG$?

Comment: You can always use a bar construction of you want something that works generically. Some classes of groups have nice constructions like right angled artin groups,and one relator groups.

Comment: The construction for right-angled Artin groups mentioned by @BenjaminSteinberg is called the Salvetti complex, for reference.

Comment: @IJL Yes, but if $G$ is a finitely presented group, do you know a (natural) model for $EG$ given by the finite presentation (and such that the $1$-skeleton is the Cayley graph of this presentation, and the $2$-skeleton its Cayley complex)?

Comment: I don't believe any general approach is known for constructing a model of EG from a finite  presentation and Stallings for example early on have a finitely presented group with no model of BG having a finite 3-skeleton.

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda the thing the OP wants is the universal cover of the Salvetti complex.  And it can be described easily as filling in the 1-skeleton of any k-cube in the Cayley graph by an actual cube.  So this is the kind of thing the OP wants but it is special to this class.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Do you see any obstruction preventing the existence of a general approach for constructing a model of $EG$ from a finite presentation? Do you have a reference for that example of Stallings? Is it torsion-free?

Comment: Yes it is a subgroup of a direct product of free groups.

Comment: Stallings paper is https://www.jstor.org/stable/2373106.   Bieri later gave similar examples where the n-skeleton of BG is finite but not the n+1 skeleton and Bestvina-Brady groups show things are very messy. So it seems hard to believe a finite presentation can lead to anything ask that nice.

Comment: Also it is undecidable is a finitely presented group has a BG with a finite 3-skeleton which again suggests something nice is hard to find

Comment: You might look at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15957/is-any-interesting-question-about-a-group-g-decidable-from-a-presentation-of-g

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: what about the construction I mentioned at the end of the post? It should provide the cubical complex you mentioned on the right-angled Artin groups. But it should work for a much larger class of groups (I guess). I wonder what it provides on the Stallings example: the first part (about irreducible $n$-blocks) should be fine (as it should be well-defined in general), but problems may occur in the second part (about geometric realization). Anyway, the first part can still be interesting/useful as a "proto"-CW-complex, a kind of "combinatorial" total space, isn't it?

Comment: I didn't read through the whole linked post. I'm not really a topologist

Comment: About the linked post: I think this "morally" makes sense, but is weak contractibility really that easy? In the Cayley 2-complex it's not true that every embedding of $S^1$ is homotopic to the border of the realization of an irreducible 2-block, that would be like saying every relator in the group is a conjugate of a defining relator (when really you have to use all products of conjugates of defining relators). Similar issues come up for higher $\pi_n$ too. I'm not saying I doubt that this complex is weakly contractible, I'm just saying, I think it's pretty hard.

Comment: @MattZaremsky: I agree that the weak contractibility should be hard. I realized that for the infinite dimensional case, leading me to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/566542/84284), and your comment makes me realize that it should be hard too in the finite dimensional case, very interesting by the way! Do you think that it would be easier to get such a Cayley $n$-complex for a group of type $F_n$ ([finiteness properties of groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finiteness_properties_of_groups)), that would be appropriate.

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux I guess I'd say that my intuition is, type $F_n$ shouldn't really help in the quest to actually extend the Cayley 2-complex to a concrete $n$-dimensional thing, either with finitely many orbits of cells, or infinitely many. With type $F_n$ groups, often the most natural complex on which the group acts has infinitely many orbits of cells, and collapsing to finitely many leaves a sort of gross (albeit finite) complex. But this is all just sort of vague intuition.

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux: Knowing a good set of generators for a group doesn't help you to find a good set of relators, so why should fixing a group presentation help you to find a good set of attaching maps for 3-cells?

Comment: @IJL: Your comment should be relevant, but I am not sure to understand what do you mean by *good*. The Cayley graph is completely determined by a (say finite) set of generators, and then a (good?) set of relators is given by the set of *irreducible* loops based on the neutral element $e$ (where irreducible means that it is not the product of two loops of strictly smaller length). I extended this idea inductively [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/478588/84284) with the notion of  *irreducible n-block*. What do you think?

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux: My point was that it is very hard to say what one means by good.  I just had a quick look at your idea of irreducible $n$-blocks.  In the case $n=1$ it has something in common with Brian Bowditch's idea of a taut loop in the Cayley graph (see his article `Continuously many quasi-isometry classes of 2-generator groups').  For larger $n$ I think there is a problem: why should (for example) a 2-block be a 2-sphere rather than say a 2-torus or some other surface?

Comment: @IJL:  a $3$-block can *be* a non-sphere surface, but then it should not be irreducible, because its $π_1$ is non-trivial and a non-nullhomotopic loop should subdivide it into smaller $3$-blocks (this argument comes from a comment of the mentioned post). Problems should arise for irreducible $n$-blocks with $n>3$, as there are non-sphere $(n−1)$-manifolds with a trivial $π_{n−2}$. So I would be very interested to know whether there exists a finitely presented torsion-free group with a non-sphere irreducible $n$-block, for some $n$.

Comment: @IJL You should keep [your first comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421998/what-about-a-cayley-n-complex-for-n2#comment1084335_421998) if you think it is still relevant.